# Athena Error- trying to turn arrays into columns - bigquery

Tags: amazon-athena, unnest

I want the several field in the event_params array to be transformed into columns.

```
select

event_date,

user_pseudo_id,

(select param.value.string_value 
from "bigquery", 
unnest(event_params) 
AS t(param) where param.key = 'buttonName')

from "bigquery"
```

I'm getting this error by only trying with one element of the array:

> SUBQUERY_MULTIPLE_ROWS: Scalar sub-query has returned multiple rows

Comment: Can you please show sample data and desired output. Note that `unnest` turns array into single column and several rows.

Answer (score 0):

So I've also been trying to figure this out. Bigquery does make it easier to extract the required data from the raw GA events.

On athena though what you'll have to do is the following:

```
select
 b.event_date,
 b.user_pseudo_id,
 s.string_value as buttonname 
from "bigquery" as b
left join (select event_name, event_timestamp, param.value.string_value from "bigquery", unnest(event_params) AS t(param) where param.key = 'buttonName') as s on s.event_name = b.event_name
                                                                                                                                                           and s.event_timestamp = b.event_timestamp
```